# Intersected Overlapped Images Horizontally

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have a requirement where images will show horizontally overlapped like an intersected view.

It will look like-
[image]

I got a link of my requirement on github.com in iOS version. You can check on https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/OnlyPictures

Hope to get help by someone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the Trick
Horizontal `RecyclerView` with `OverlapDecoration` and `HeaderView`
Apply this `ItemDecoration` to `RecyclerView`

```
public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final static int vertOverlap = -20;

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, vertOverlap, 0);

    }
}
```

And

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlapDecoration());
```

For reverse Stack use this `LinearLayoutManager`

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[Overlapping_RecyclerView](https://github.com/naveendew/Overlapping_RecyclerView)

[image: Preview]

Comment: the horizontal recyclerview is getting distorted when used within another recyclerview.

Comment: After wasting the whole day, you gave the right answer.. thnx @AkashSharma

Answer (score 0):

what i think is, there are 6 static `ImageView` with fixed size in a Relative layout. with `marginLeft` `-10dp`(accordingly). And last one is Button with +9 or other count text with text size and bold text.

I haven't tried it but i think it will work.

Comment: No this is not static as you can see there is more images at last right. It will be dynamically added and it will scroll too. You can see the github link which I have shared.

Comment: @HariNJha  than you can try with `Horizontal recyclerview` with `round_image view` as items. and you need to show the count as `count = totalsize - lastVisibleView_position` .. and for overlapping i think you need to play with item height at run time.